# Boostrap 4 responsive card deck equal height card footers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have setup a responsive card layout using bootstrap 4 `card-deck` class utility. All seems to work as expected, although i'd like to line up the top of the footers, as opposed to the default behaviour of simply bottom aligning the `footer` and allowing it to spill upwards. I'm not sure how to apply equal height footers on a per row basis using flex? I don't want to use js for this as i've managed to build the entire page using only flex.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nus1v4ak/4/

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="card-deck">
    <li class="col-xs-4 card col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <!-- more <li> elements as above but with random content of different sizes -->

  </ul>
</div>
```

Current output:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Kindly check the edited section of my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.card:nth-child(1) .card-footer,
.card:nth-child(2) .card-footer,
.card:nth-child(3) .card-footer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

My suggestion is to kindly add this in your CSS of the fiddle you shared, you can check the results as well!! 
I have used `:nth-child()` property with main `.card` class and applied the effects... Still you can ask for any explanation!!

**Same height for each footer-**

```
.card-footer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

height of 100px will be applied to each footer regardless of content!!!

**Responsive height based on device screen's width-**

```
.card-footer {
  height: 5vw;
}
```

now your height is responsive and will change according t the needs and dimensions of the browser screen, height is not short(small) or constant anymore!!

Comment: please accept my answer if your desired output is achieved

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is that this requires a set height on the footer. I need a solution that equalises the height regardless of content.

Comment: do you want same height for each footer?.. Then it's simple as cake walk...

Comment: I agree, hard coding a set height is incredibly simple. But as the content is dynamic, 100px maybe too small.

Comment: then specify height in terms of vw or vh... VW means view port's width and Vh means view port's height... It will be dynamic then

Comment: But the height needs to be determined by the content, not the viewport. The footer should be either large or small based on the content, regardless of the viewport.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215983/discussion-between-om-chaudhary-and-steve).

Answer (score 0):

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4gh26do/)

```
.card:nth-child(1) .card-footer,
.card:nth-child(2) .card-footer,
.card:nth-child(3) .card-footer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

kindly use your desired height now

Comment: Is this what you want?